# Is There Anything Wrong With Publishing Signed Jars To An Internal Repo?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I have 250 dependencies (mostly open source ones ones like spring, commons etc) that I need for my Java webstart application. I have to sign every single one of these each time I do a build and it slows my build right down.

I was thinking of signing them once and publishing them to my internal nexus with a "signed" classifier then using the classifier in the dependencies in my gradle script.

Is anything wrong with this?

Comment: I don't have any problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a good idea, but you should define a profile in your pom.xml to enable resigning all jars when needed (like when certificate changes)